# Endless INFO Client: Application report for application_xx (state: ACCEPTED) messages for Spark submit on Yarn

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When I submit Spark application using Hadoop with Yarn in cluster mode. 
Yarn client State stucks in Accepted state and it never change to Running. I am Using Centos 7 Hadoop Cluster which has 1 Master 2 Slaves

I login to openstack with floating IP(which we externally associate) This IP is different from IP address we get we do ifconfig in system.

Below are the logs:

```
    18/01/21 16:34:19 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/local/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.1.jar -> hdfs://192.168.198.10:8020/user/cloud-user/.sparkStaging/application_1516548465362_0014/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.1.jar
    18/01/21 16:34:19 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-f37b5cec-a81f-46c3-9b5e-6ce7854c6dd4/__spark_conf__2008488553335511154.zip -> hdfs://192.168.198.10:8020/user/cloud-user/.sparkStaging/application_1516548465362_0014/__spark_conf__.zip
    18/01/21 16:34:19 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: cloud-user
    18/01/21 16:34:19 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: cloud-user
    18/01/21 16:34:19 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
    18/01/21 16:34:19 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
    18/01/21 16:34:19 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(cloud-user); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(cloud-user); groups with modify permissions: Set()
    18/01/21 16:34:19 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application application_1516548465362_0014 to ResourceManager
    18/01/21 16:34:19 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1516548465362_0014
    18/01/21 16:34:20 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1516548465362_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
    18/01/21 16:34:20 INFO yarn.Client: 
                client token: N/A
                diagnostics: N/A
                ApplicationMaster host: N/A
                ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
                queue: default
                start time: 1516552459599
                tracking URL: http://master.abc.com:8088/proxy/application_1516548465362_0014/
                user: cloud-user

    18/01/21 16:34:21 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1516548465362_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
    18/01/21 16:34:22 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1516548465362_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
    18/01/21 16:34:23 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1516548465362_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
    18/01/21 16:34:24 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1516548465362_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
    18/01/21 16:34:25 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1516548465362_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
    18/01/21 16:34:26 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1516548465362_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
    18/01/21 16:34:27 yarn.Client: Application report for application_1516548465362_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
```

Tried all options which people have suggested but nothing work.I see node has enough space but not sure why this is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please add the logs / output from the `tracking URL` to the question

Comment: Below are the name node logs after submitting spark application:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DisallowedDatanodeException:Datanode denied communication with namenode because hostname cannot be resolved (ip=192.168.198.12, hostname=192.168.198.12): DatanodeRegistration(0.0.0.0:50010, datanodeUuid=318760a1-e852-423d-a30b-0ec7e90bdd7b, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020
2018-01-21 13:05:49,629 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: Unresolved datanode registration: hostname cannot be resolved (ip=192.168.198.11, hostname=192.168.198.11)

Answer (score 0):

> Unresolved datanode registration: hostname cannot be resolved (ip=192.168.198.11, hostname=192.168.198.11)

I don't think the hostname should be an IP, but you need to update `/etc/hosts` on each machine to tell it where the slaves and masters are, or you need either static IPs or use a DNS server  to resolve address for machines that float on the network

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i will try your suggestion.I have one doubt - since i am working on openstack instances i do have actual and floating IP of the servers.So should i refer only floating IPs in my all config/xml files where ever its needed ? Thanks Again!!

Comment: 127.0.0.1 master.target.com master
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 master.target.com master
::1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

10.63.107.55 master.target.com master
10.63.107.73 slave-1.target.com slave-1
10.63.107.77 slave-2.target.com slave-2

Comment: Okay, so looks like your network is `10.63.x.x`, so you need to figure out why it wants to connect to a datanode on the private network `192.168.x.x`. In the future, you might want to remove the domain name from your public posts, by the way